# Git: editing hunks fails (when file has other hunks?)

Tags: git

Given a file with contents:

```
foo
bar
baz

foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo

foo
bar
baz
```

When I edit this file to become

```
foo
bar1
baz

foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo

foo
bar1
baz
```

(replaced `bar`s with `bar1`s)

When I run `git add --patch` and edit the first hunk

```
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 foo
-bar
+bar1
 baz

 foo
```

To become

```
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 foo
-bar
+bar2
 baz

 foo
```

(replaced `+bar1` with `+bar2`)

I get the following error

```
error: patch fragment without header at line 12: @@ -15,5 +15,5 @@ foo
Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]?
```

It is not clear to me why this edit would fail.

Git version: 2.17.0

Comment: It's not clear to me either, I'm able to do the same change successfully, though on windows. [`git add -p`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfKlF.png) [`git diff --cached`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9anQE.png).

Comment: @JeffMercado same git version?

Comment: I just switched back to 2.16.2 and it works. If someone else can reproduce on 2.17.0, this might be a bug. https://public-inbox.org/git/01010162c940b8bb-d8139971-3ee2-4cd6-bb19-35126d46753b-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com/#R

Comment: Sorry, I thought I included in my screenshots. Same version on windows. `git version 2.17.0.windows.1`

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be a regression in 2.17.0.

I filed this issue on the Git mailing list and the community there kindly helped me identity the issue.

My question: https://public-inbox.org/git/20180510104136.8653-1-oliverjash@gmail.com/

The answer: https://public-inbox.org/git/be321106-2f10-e678-8237-449d2dd30fee@talktalk.net/

The problem turned out to be that my editor was trimming trailing whitespace from context lines when editing the hunks. In this example it was the space on the empty line between `baz` and `foo`.

This appears to be a change in behaviour since Git 2.17.0, as explained in this email: https://public-inbox.org/git/be321106-2f10-e678-8237-449d2dd30fee@talktalk.net/.

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm it happens on macOS Mojave with standard git from command line tools (2.17.2). git 2.19.2 from homebrew doesn't suffer from the issue.